# Link rate between EMC DAE and HBA

Tags: networking, emc

I have a EMC DAE (KTN-STL4) drive cage directly connected to a HP Proliant server using a QLogic QLE2560 HBA. I'm using copper cable between the HBA card and the DAE. On the controller card in the DAE there is a label that states "4Gb". I'm guessing that this means 4Gbit/s. But if I set the HBA card to "Auto speed" it negotiate 2Gbit/s, and if I hard set it to 4Gbit/s I end up with no link.

Why is this? Isn't the DAE controller card capable of link speed higher then 2Gbit/s or is it the copper cable that limits the speed, or is it the interface used between the DAE and Qlogic HBA that is the problem? I have been browsing for HSSDC-FC converters and they always seems to på rated at ~2Gbit/s. If this is the limit, why does it say 4Gb on the controller cards in the DAE?

Answer (score 0):

Check the settings on the bios of the qlogic hba, to see if there's some setting limiting the port speed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the original EMC DAE cable???  Because just like the ethernet standard CAT5, CAT5e and CAT6 which are rated at different speeds, your cable might be rated at 2Gb and not 4Gb. I would recommend that you re-examine the "sfp to hssdc2" cable and make sure its rated at 4Gb also the length of the cable can affect the speed.